# XCode warnings highlight code in wrong file

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a very strange problem with XCode, currently version 7.1, but Xcode 6 has exhibited the same issue before I updated.

Let's say I have an include file A.h that contains code that generates a warning in line number 102. That file is included by B.cpp in line 10. Now when I compile, XCode highlights the line 102 in file B.cpp with a yellow warning tag, which is completely wrong, because the warning is generated by line 102 in file A.h!

Curiously, if you go to the build log in XCode, clangs output is completely correct:

```
In file included from /Users/philipp/bla/B.cpp:10:
In file included from bla/B.h:16:
/Users/philipp/bla/A.h:102:36: warning: 'this' pointer cannot be null in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be assumed to always evaluate to false [-Wtautological-undefined-compare]
```

So one would expect XCode to highlight A.h, line 102.
However, XCode highlights B.cpp, line 102, which is completely unrelated to the warning!
Curiously, XCode *does* also highlight A.h, line 102, but I only see this if I manually open this file and look for the line because I saw it in the clang output log. I never get to see it if I click the warning in the sidebar.

Is this a known problem of XCode with C++ code (I know C++ in XCode is more of an afterthought, as it is really made for Obj-C)?

Comment: I haven't experienced anything like this. Can you provide step-by-step instructions on how I could reproduce this myself?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your compiler flags. Often having a bad C/C++ flag can throw a CLANG warning (like Optimization flag '-finline-functions' is not supported) which seems to cause this kind of craziness.